# Nginx serve custom css file

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

lets say, I have an location `/user/username/custom/custom.css` I would like to server this location `/user/(.*)/custom/` to the location `/var/www/custom` I don't know, how to write NginX rules.
I tried

```
location ~* /user/(.*)/custom/ {
   alias /var/www/custom/; 
}
```

but such rule doesn't work.

Any suggestions please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well mine was similar to this

```
location ~* /user/[^/]+/custom/(.*) {
   alias /var/www/custom/$1;
}
```

Yours suffer from the issue that below will results in the same files

```
/user/username/abc/test/custom/test.css
/user/username/abc/custom/test.css
/user/username/custom/test.css
```

Mine will give 404 on first 2 and give you the proper file on last one

Comment: Yes, I understand...this is better one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally I figured it out. The right solution (at least I hope so) is

```
location ~* /user/(.*)/custom/(.*) {
   alias /var/www/custom/$2; 
}
```